# Rotate background-image url every 10 seconds

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, loops, cycle

I've seen a lot of similar questions but couldn't find a resolution. I have a bootstrap jumbotron and a set of 3 images to cycle through it every 10 seconds. The problem is that the first url doesn't show until the first 10 seconds has passed. After the array finishes the images play correctly, it's only on first load that the image is blank. I've tried setting the background-image via CSS and JQuery, but still encountered issues with skipping when loading the first image.

The Code

```js
var jumbotronBG = ['/image1.jpg', '/image2.jpg', '/image3.jpg'];
var changeImage = $(".jumbotron");
  var i = 0;
 
setInterval(function() {
  changeImage.css({'background-image': 'url(' + jumbotronBG[i] + ")"});
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == jumbotronBG.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">


</div>
```

Just need to find a way to cycle all 3 images with the fist being image1.jpg when the page loads.

Comment: changeImage.css({'background-image': 'url(' + mainIndexGif[i] + ')'}); is the current use of ticks/quotes

Comment: Just set the css of `.jumbotron` in your `.css` file to `background-image: url(/image1.jpg)` and then whe you page loads it will be the first image, then just start the interval at 2 for the very first time after page load.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: since you are using Bootstrap, why don't you use Bootstrap's [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)? I think you can add html into each item so you can set a background image for each element. And you can adjust the time between transitions with options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong except for not calling the `background-image` change on load? Changed JavaScript code to fix this:

```
var jumbotronBG = ['https://placehold.it/100x100', 'https://placehold.it/200x200', 'https://placehold.it/300x300'];
var changeImage = $(".jumbotron");
var i = 0;

function cycleImage() {
  changeImage.css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + jumbotronBG[i] + ")"
  });
  i = i + 1;
  if (i == jumbotronBG.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(cycleImage, 1000);
cycleImage();
```

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7orzrhh/1/) works as you intended right?

Comment: You're exactly right @leroydev. Thank you. Can't believe I missed it.